# How do I append to the PATH environment variable for a BuildBot ShellCommand

Tags: python, environment-variables, buildbot

I need to alter the build environment variable for a build step. However the current environment parameter only replaces existing environment variables.

Does anybody know how I can get buildbot to append to the PATH environment variable rather than replace:

```
my_return.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["qmake", "{0}.pro".format(pro_name)],
                               env={'PATH': qt_path}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend/append to the PATH environment variable by putting `$PATH` at the end of the existing value. Something like:

```
my_return.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["qmake", "{0}.pro".format(pro_name)],
                               env={'PATH': [qt_path, "${PATH}"]}))
```

More details at the buildbot [documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#step-ShellCommand).

Comment: Is `${PATH}` going to be resolved to the value of `PATH` as it exists in the environment of the master process or as it exists in the environment of the slave? There's a difference. I did not see any clear information in the documentation. (By the way you've pointed your documentation link to a version of Buildbot that has not been released yet.)

Comment: My Windows buildslave was version 0.8.4 and it failed with an error "exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer", however once I upgraded to 0.8.12 the environment worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Louis Since the `ShellCommand` is going to be executed on the slave, `PATH` environment variable is from the slave. I updated the doc link to the latest release. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the path is for `qmake` why don't you just use the full path to the program as the first argument, instead of forcing the shell to look for it?

*i.e.* suppose `qt_path` is `/home/qt/bin`, just write

```
my_return.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["/home/qt/bin/qmake",
                                 "{0}.pro".format(pro_name)]))
```